# My Firebase based Login app keeps stopping. I couldn't find the solution

Tags: java, android, android-studio, firebase

Here the full project: https://github.com/nahid1146/AdmissionHelper 
There are two buttons in the main activity. Sign Up and Log In. Whenever I click on these two buttons, the app keeps exiting.


I think the problem is in the 3 java files or in the gradle bundle. Couldn't figure out any solution.

Comment: We're not here to debug your project for you. Please share the [minimal code that reproduces the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (read the link, its quite useful).

Comment: I know. I am sorry for that. But it's a very little project. Just 10/15 line or less in each 3 java files. MainActivity, SignInActivity, SignUpActivity. I couldn't figure out where's the exact problem is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your xml files change

`com.rengwuxian.materialedittext.MaterialAutoCompleteTextView`

to

`com.rengwuxian.materialedittext.MaterialEditText`

In your app the files *activity_sign_up.xml* and *activity_sign_in.xml* you have `MaterialAutoCompleteTextView` as `com.rengwuxian.materialedittext.MaterialAutoCompleteTextView`.

But the in your .java source files you cast the `MaterialAutoCompleteTextView` to `MaterialEditText`.

when you lunch the activities you get an exception

> com.rengwuxian.materialedittext.MaterialAutoCompleteTextView **cannot be cast to** com.rengwuxian.materialedittext.MaterialEditText